# How to change the fxml file after doing an action?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm about to finish with a database application and I could not find a solution on how to change the code and default values which are written in the fxml file of a controller.

I have a Tableview with columns and CheckMenuItems for those columns. The CheckMenuItems for those columns who are selected should be the visible columns. The Non-Selected Items should not be visible.

I already had success doing that like this, that the columns disappear after I unselect the CheckMenuItem:

```
    @FXML
        public void checkNR(ActionEvent event) {
            if(!checkMenuItemNR.isSelected()) {
                tablecolumnNR.setVisible(false);
            }
            if(checkMenuItemNR.isSelected()) {
                tablecolumnNR.setVisible(true);
            }
```

My Expected results are fine so far when using the program once. But if I start it again everything is set to default again and I see all the columns.

What I want is to change the last line in the code below, that selected will set to false if I unselect that CheckMenuItem.

```
 <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Spalten">
           <items>
              <CheckMenuItem fx:id="checkMenuItemNR" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#checkNR" selected="true" text="NR" />
```

[CheckMenuItems for each column selected at the start of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ohpf.png)

[colums disappear if I unselect a menu item, but when I restart I want that to stay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzVVk.png)

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having. Right now, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You're going to need to look at storing the configuration as either Properties or in the Database, based on for whom/where your application runs.  When the program starts load it up and set them to the menu values, on close save them.  You cannot change the FXML file at runtime.

Comment: @kendavidson I had the possibilities of storing it in the database or in the properties (windows register) also in my mind, but I was eager to find a solution changing the fxml file at or after runtime. Its unfortunate, that there is no way to change it in the fxml file then

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, you're probably better off saving the settings/configuration in properties or database.  BUT..... if you absolutely need to change the FXML file, you can save it's contents on file or database.  It's not the greatest solution, but I have seen it done in the past.  A previous company of mine allowed users to modify FXML files by user group, which isn't exactly the same (essentially it was an infrequent save) where if you do this, you'll be needing to save the FXML content each exit/change.

At a high level you'll need to:

- Read the file in and process the DOM manually, after each property change.
- Write the updated file contents to disk or database
- Update your fxml loading to look at disk/database first, and if nothing exists then fall back to the resource version

It's possible, but it's not pretty - specifically on a user by user by property level.  The most annoying part will be updating the DOM each time a button click is done.